# On change event does not return new values

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Very strange issue appeared today, i had written a javascript code to get values from dynamically generated input fields. It was working fine with no issue, today it started returning default values, following is the code:

```js
$(document).on("change", "#myprofile .pf_name", function() {
  var field_name = $(this).attr("name"); // this the name of field i get on the input

  var field_value = $('input[name=' + field_name + ']').val(); //this is the value i am getting from the that input, working fine recently

  // I am wriring new value in input box and then when this onchange event triggers it 
  //retruns default value that was loaded dynamically with the loop. 
  //However it should return new written value. It was working fine previously.
  console.log("field name: " + field_name + " field value: " + field_value); 
});
```

It seems something is blocking or having issue in whole code. However i have checked through all the code but couldnot find any suspicious code.

Here is another try:

I generate input area by jquery with a class name to it. Once it is generated with default value lets say : Testing. Now when i write new text : 12345 and trigger the click event on other button to get this input value it returns : Testing < default value

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would help to see a working example of the problem here. However the code seems rather redundant as you could just use `$(this).val()` or `this.value` instead

Comment: What is the point of going back to the DOM to find the `<input>` when `this` already refers to it directly?

Comment: @RobertFrenette the OP can already do that with this logic

Comment: @RobertFrenette it is not looking for ID's , it is looking for a class and there can be any number of that class. Event delegation is a very common practice and often alleviates other code complexity

Comment: Thank you all, but the issue seems with DOM as it is not updating the value on input with the value i am writing. Whenever i try to get value of input via .class it returns old default value but not updated value.

Comment: `$(selector).val()` can only get value of the first matching selector in the page. Please provide a [mcve] also

Comment: If you didn't miss the quoted string then $('input[name="' + field_name + '"]').val();

Comment: @RobertFrenette you may want to double check all of that because everything about it is wrong in this case.